# Auto refresh JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

Here's the scenario:
- there is a set of variables
- these variables indicate the statuses of various equipment
- the goal is to display an always-updated status chart

So, I have gotten as far as having a parser in Perl that spits out JavaScript `var x = 'y';` type code, and now I'm looking for how to have the HTML or other JavaScript automatically check for updates to this "spit out" code, versus just caching it after the first time.

The closest thing I've seen is to use "setInterval" to have it execute a function, so I went ahead and wrapped the "var" statements in a function with a "setInterval" timer. But will this reliably be always up-to-date, or does it cache the whole function, depending on the browser?

EDIT: I'm not currently using any libraries or anything, and would prefer not to - but I will if I have to.

EDIT2: Finally found what I'm looking for. http://www.philnicholas.com/2009/05/11/reloading-your-javascript-without-reloading-your-page/

Just had to modify the last line to get it to work.

Comment: I'd do this with an AJAX call myself to get the data and refresh the page with the fresh results. You can use setTimeout to time the updates (better than setInterval, as there's no conditionality to its execution).

Comment: Dude, seriously just try Meteor. You will be more than happy

Comment: Use AJAX and web sockets

Comment: Create a page that will give you the `y` in your example in the form `{"x": "y"}` (this is JSON-formatted). Create a function that uses AJAX to *asynchronously* request this data from that URL. Set the variable on page load, and then re-request it either with a `setInterval()` request to the same function, or a call to a function that executes it's own `setImeout()` (and calls itself when finished).

Comment: its definitely harder to parse the code out of human text then vice versa
**NP != P solved**!

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'm almost following, but not quite... should I be searching for how to create an asynchronous AJAX function? I know I'm missing something, but I don't know what to search for to find it.

Comment: Try to explain your problem a bit better. I am not sure what the issue is or how you get values.

Answer (score 1):

You're already close to the solution. Create a function that makes an ajax call to the 'spit out' you have written in perl.

```
function getSpitOut() {
    $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "GET", 
            url: "spit_out.pl", 
            data: "x=8&y=7",
            success: function(msg){
                // UPDATE CHART      
            }        
      });
}
```

And another function to make the ajax calls at intervals:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(getSpitOut, 60000);       // Call getSpitOut every 60s
})
```

The browser won't cache it because you're updating the chart based on the server side perl script.

Comment: This doesn't look like pure JavaScript... is this using a library?

Comment: Using jQuery... i hate it myself, but every freaking website uses it today, it has become a 'must have' if you are talking to anybody about JS. People just assume jQuery is present.

Comment: Got it. Would the non-jQuery equivalent be much more complex?

Comment: The non-jquery equivalent isn't complex. It's something around XMLHttpRequests for the $.ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I never closed this.

Slightly modified from: "http://www.philnicholas.com/2009/05/11/reloading-your-javascript-without-reloading-your-page/", I have this:

```
var docHeadObj = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var dynamicScript = document.createElement("script");
dynamicScript.type = "text/javascript";
dynamicScript.src = scriptName;
docHeadObj.appendChild(dynamicScript);
```